# Closing channel drops the queue: how to avoid it

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

In RabbitMQ, using C# client, when I close an with `IModel.Close()` (i.e. *a channel*), the target queue gets dropped.

I can't figure out how I can prevent this behavior after some trial-errors.

The whole queue is *durable* and the server isn't restarted. Queue is just dropped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy to solve: channels should be both durable and have `autoDelete` set to false when they're declared. Same goes for queues.